Is it possible to navigate forward/backward only within tabs of the same window?
I'm a long time Emacs/evil-mode, Vim and VSCode user.
One thing that I use a lot in Emacs/Vim is that navigating back/forward to my previous/next cursor position only navigates within buffers of the same window (i.e. it doesn't jump across from 1 window to another). This helps me maintain 2 (or more) different navigation contexts.
Is there a way to do this in VSCode? Happy to elaborate if my description is unclear!
I've tried the out-of-the-box navigateBackward/Forward commands as well as VSCode Vim's navigation and it jumps from window to window (when I have multiple windows).

I'm going to assume that by "window", you mean "editor group". if you mean by tab, then dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67693251/11107541.
